# Fortran loop crashes when using parallel do

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran

I have some code that crashes when I use !$OMP PARALLEL DO,
but runs ok without it. The loop is below and the problem occurs when I use the function "collision"

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
  DO i=1,M-1
    IF(W(i)%link.EQ.0) THEN
      DO j=i+1,M   
        IF(W(j)%link.EQ.0) THEN  
          IF( collision( W(i)%R , W(j)%R , cDist ) ) THEN

              CALL death(i)
              CALL death(j)
              collisions = collisions + 1
              EXIT

          END IF
        END IF
      END DO
    END IF
  END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

The function "collision" is below, and the problem occurs when I use the function "q" when N = 3

```
LOGICAL FUNCTION collision( R1 , R2 , cDist)
USE DMCVariables , ONLY : N , bohr
REAL*8 , INTENT(IN) :: R1(N,3) , R2(N,3) 
REAL , INTENT(IN) :: cDist
REAL :: radSq 
INTEGER :: k , l , m

  radSq = (bohr*cDist)**2 
  collision = .FALSE.

  IF(N.EQ.2) THEN
    IF( distSq( R1(1,:) , R2(2,:) ).LT.radSq ) THEN
      IF( distSq( R1(2,:) , R2(1,:) ).LT.radSq ) THEN
        collision = .TRUE.
      END IF
    END IF
  END IF

  IF(N.EQ.3) THEN
    DO k=1,N-1
      DO l=k,N
        IF( distSq( R1(k,:) , R2(l,:) ).LT.radSq ) THEN
          IF( distSq( R1(l,:) , R2(k,:) ).LT.radSq ) THEN
            IF( distSq( R1(q(k,l),:) , R2(q(k,l),:) ).LT.radSq ) THEN
              collision = .TRUE.
            END IF
          END IF
        END IF
      END DO
    END DO
  END IF

END FUNCTION collision
```

The function "q" is below, and it should return a number from 1 to 3. But when I use parallel do it returns 21972 most of the time, which is out of bounds.

```
INTEGER FUNCTION q(l,k)
INTEGER , INTENT(IN) :: l , k

  IF(l.EQ.1.AND.k.EQ.2.OR.l.EQ.2.AND.k.EQ.1) q = 3
  IF(l.EQ.1.AND.k.EQ.3.OR.l.EQ.3.AND.k.EQ.1) q = 2
  IF(l.EQ.2.AND.k.EQ.3.OR.l.EQ.3.AND.k.EQ.2) q = 1

END FUNCTION q
```

Comment: If it is returning a random number, maybe `q` is not being assigned at all inside the function. I mean, what happens if none of the 3 `if` statements get executed? Could you add a guard clause, where you assign a known number to `q`, like -1, and check if it is it?

Comment: Where is the code of `death`?

Comment: In collision the inner loop is Do l = k, n   - should this be from k+1? The q function doesn't cope with the case when its arguments are equal, which would result in symptoms similar to those you are seeing due to an undefined variable.

Comment: Oh, and real*8 is horrible, not standard, never has been standard, and it would really help if you provided a complete program if you want us to help sort out things like this